# What other APIs are available for hotels?

Tags: api

I am looking for APIs that allow hotel operators to update room information and other hotel info programatically, so far I have only found Expedia QuickConnect but I cannot find anything else. Anyone know of other APIs?

Just to reiterate these are APIs to manage a hotel (rooms, prices etc) not to search for hotel rooms.

Comment: Not to nitpick or anything, but who would want to trust sensitive and important information such as that, with a 3rd party? Anyway, you really ought to ensure the hotel management would really allow this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

search for amadeus api and galileo api..that should help..amadeus is the largest network..
thanx
avi